# Mongoose within().circle() and $near gives result distinct to Mongo Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I have a Node.js test in wich multiple Objects simulates to move away from some point in a map and Im countinuously testing if they´re within a radious from that point.
Each object corresponds to a Model with a nested legacy 2d Index `'location.loc'`.

I have used this queries

```
var center={_lat:20,lng:-100};

var area = { 
      center: [center._lng,center._lat], 
      radius: 100,//This are supossed to be meters
      unique: true,
      spherical: true }


  MyModel.where('location.loc')
         .within()
         .circle(area)
         .exec(function (err, records) {
            if (err) { 
              throw err; 
            }
            //Log Length of records
         });
```

And

```
  MyModel.find({  
    "location.loc": {
      $near: [center._lng,center._lat],
      $maxDistance: 1 //This is suposed to be a mile
    }
    }).exec(function(err, documents) {
        if (err) { 
          throw err; 
        }
        //Log documents length
    });
```

But both scripts returns me te entire collection of documents, even when they are miles away from the point.
At the same time im doing the same queries in my Mongo client with $near,$geoWithin and those queries gives me the right answer.

What is wrong with my Mongoose scripts?

Should only thest with within().circle() for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn out that the radius in the first code are wrongly defined.
In this [Mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) says

> With spherical: true, if you specify a GeoJSON point, MongoDB uses meters as the unit of measurement

But this is for a GeoJSON point and for `geoNear`.
For the legacy coordinate format [long,lat], we must divide the radius value in miles by 3963.2 to cast it as radians. See this [Example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/#example).